# add prompt to OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, winforms, openfiledialog

I am writing a Windows Forms application in which the user is asked to successively select a file corresponding to a task: one specific file for each task. 
As it works now, the user is prompted to select a file corresponding to the current task and the task name is specified on the previous window, before the OpenFileDialog is invoked. I am afraid that after a number of iterations, the user will not recall the task he is currently selecting the file for. 
The obvious solution is to present the prompt containing the task name on the same Window with the OpenFileDialog. 
As the OpenFileDialog is a sealed class, it cannot be inherited from. 
Is there a way to do it short of coding my own file selection tool?

Comment: see my edit - hope it helps !

Answer (score 2):

You could set the `Title` of your `Dialog` to display info on what task is related.

**OR**

Why not show a `MessageBox` in advance (sth. like this) ?

```
MessageBox.Show("Please select file for TASK 00001", "Select File");

//Execution will continue on UserClick on OK on that MessageBox => User should have read 
that message and should know what task is related

OpenFileDialog dialog = new OpenFileDialog();
dialog.Title = "SELECT FILE FOR <YOUR TASKNAME GOES HERE>";
if(dialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string path = dialog.FileName;
    //Continue with your logic
}
```

[image]

**UPDATE:**

Have a look at the [documentation for `OpenFileDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog(v=vs.110).aspx).
There is a `Event` called `FileOK` which is fired on selecting a file.
You could implement sth. like this:

```
private void Dialog_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{
    DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("ARE U SURE ?", "?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);
    switch (result)
    {
        case DialogResult.Cancel:
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
        case DialogResult.Yes:
            break;
        case DialogResult.No:
            e.Cancel = true;
            break;
    }            
}
```

Don't forget to attach to that event:

```
dialog.FileOk += Dialog_FileOk;
```

[image]

You could ask `"Is this the correct file for TASK XYZ"` for example. Also with `e.Cancel = true;` you can abort the selection and the dialog remains opened.

Comment: Thank you for the idea but I do not see an appreciable improvement over the current situation, as the task name is not visible during the actual process of selecting the file.

Comment: It will be visible on the dialogs header bar ? Isn't that useful enough ?

Comment: This does also not improve the situation. I want the user to see the task name while the file selection process is under way and not afterwards.

Comment: @user2102327 And where do you wish to see that name ? - **Remember** -  the header is showing the TaskName as long as the dialog is open ..

Comment: Felix D. If I could inherit from the OpenFileDialog, I would place a TextBox at the top of the Window with the task name colored in blue or something.

Comment: @user2102327 that's not possible. But srsly how is that *alot* different from the exising header ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156326/discussion-between-user2102327-and-felix-d).